# MySQL Transaction isolation levels

Tags: java, percona

Currently i'm looking for the best Transaction isolation levels for MySQL server, i'm doing an accounting desktop application, so i have to decide which Transaction isolation level i should use.
i have read all of them, but i need your experiences to decide.

I'm using MySQL (Percona server) Latest update.
Java Programming language.

Comment: what have you decided?

Answer (score 0):

Which isolation level to use depends on the nature of your application.

What types of queries you run, and in what order, etc. will influence which isolation level is appropriate.

There is no such thing as 'the best' isolation level, in general.

You should use the weakest transaction level you can that is safe for your application.
Or, if performance does not matter, and you just want the safest option, use serializable - you will likely get deadlocks during concurrent queries, though.

The stronger the isolation level (eg: serializable), the worse the performance, and vice-versa.

Have a read: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isolation_%28database_systems%29